# What happens with the remaining events if the number of events exceeds the maxevents argument given to epoll_wait()?

Tags: c, linux, events, posix, epoll

Is epoll chivalrous enough to hold onto the remaining events, and put them into the events array the next time epoll_wait() is called? Or does it simply trash them like a total jerk?

The man page neglects to mention this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgetting the events would be...extremely rude to the programmer.  Anything based on edge-triggered epoll would stop working under load.

**EDIT**:  I forgot to mention that epoll will not forget about events that it hasn't returned to user code, barring those cases where the underlying file has been closed.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I was searching for precisely this question.

I do have 1 question though -- How long does it remember? What happens to the TCP connection state if we don't pick up that event for too long?